# xmltodict with force_list argument returns a list with None element for empty XML list

Tags: python, parsing, xmltodict

I'm parsing XML with `xmltodict` with `force_list=('xml_tag')` in order to get list for single elements in XML list. And it works! However, in case when `xml_tag` has no child it returns a `[None]`(list with single `None` object). How to prevent it?

**XML**

```
<Something>
    <Guitar>
        <name>Walden</name>
        <strings>5</strings>
    </Guitar>
    <Pokemons>
    </Pokemons>
</Something>
```

**PYTHON**

```
res = xmltodict.parse(xml, force_list=('Pokemons',))

res = res['Something']['Guitar']['Pokemons']

pprint(res)

>>> [None]
```

Any suggestions?

**[UPDATE]**

Sorry, I'm not clarifying what I want.
I want to get empty list as result not list with None element

Comment: What do you want to prevent, having list of None, None or the value at all ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a postprocessing function to xmltodict, which allows you to modify the dict values.
But postprocecssing needs to return a key and a value:

```
import xmltodict
import json


def postprocessor(path, key, value):
    if key == 'Pokemons' and not value:
        return key, []
    return key, value

xml = """<Something>
    <Guitar>
        <name>Walden</name>
        <strings>5</strings>
    </Guitar>
    <Pokemons>
    </Pokemons>
</Something>"""


res = xmltodict.parse(xml, postprocessor=postprocessor)
print(json.dumps(res, indent=2, sort_keys=True))
```

Output:

```
{
  "Something": {
    "Guitar": {
      "name": "Walden",
      "strings": "5"
    },
    "Pokemons": []
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`xmltodict.parse` (with force_list arg) convert xml to a `OrderedDict` with tag as key irrespective for if node is empty or not (in case of empty node `None` value is stored in dict).

Therefore you have to filter your dict result for `None` yourself.

To filter dict you can define your custom method:

```
def filter_dict(item):
    if not item:
        return ''
    elif isinstance(item, list):
        return [it for it in item if it]
    elif not hasattr(item, 'items'):
        return item
    else:
        return {key: filter_dict(value) for key, value in item.items()}


>>> res = xmltodict.parse(xml, force_list=('Pokemons',))
>>> res = filter_dict(res)
>>> pokemons = res['Something']['Pokemons']
>>> pokemons
>>> []
```